# Trusted Proxy change from Laravel 8 to Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

I am upgrading my project from Laravel 8 to Laravel 9. And in the [**Trusted Proxies**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method) section in upgrade guide it is mentioned that you may need to make changes to the file only if you are

> importing your existing application code into a totally new Laravel 9 application skeleton

I am not doing it this way, I am upgrading my existing codebase to Laravel 9. And my `app/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php` file doesn't have the new Illuminate `TrustProxies` It is the old Fideloper one.

Also my headers property looks like this:

`protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL;`

Should I not make those changes because I am not importing my code into Laravel 9 Skeleton? or the documentation has it backwards?

Comment: I think in Laravel 9 we don't need the Trustproxies package from the composer.
You can simply remove by composer remove fideloper/proxy  and update your packages by composer update command.
it's properly mentioned in the laravel 9 upgrade guide. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#the-assert-deleted-method